# Store phonetics in plain text field

Tags: craft3, database, field, plaintext

I need to store phonetics for word definitions in a plain text field. An example would be something like "Craft Website" => `\ ˈkraft ˈweb-ˌsīt \`, like you'd see in a dictionary.

If I try saving `\ ˈkraft ˈweb-ˌsīt \` in a custom plain text field, I get a database exception, presumably because it takes issue with all the unusual characters not found in UTF-8.

[image]

Does Craft have a way to handle this without needing to [manually adjust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399578/how-to-store-phonetics-in-mysql-database) my database?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Craft have a way to handle this without needing to manually adjust my database?

Swap to [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)? :)

This is more of a MySQL limitation/configuration issue than a Craft/PHP one.

You can alter the charset/collation of the column the plain text field is being saved to `utf8_mb4` and `utf8mb4_general_ci` and that should solve it.